# SQL statement no working for C# database search

Tags: c#, sql

Im trying to have my program search my database and add the results to a listview control. The listview populates with a SQL statement of:
`SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations`

However when I try to make it search with a where statement and add values it keeps returning nothing

```
String selStmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE @SearchParameter = @SearchTerm";
SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selStmt, conn);
selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchParameter", SearchParameter);
selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", SearchTerm);
```

So SearchParameter would have for example "City" (searching the City column) and SearchTerm would have "Leeds" (Searching for Leeds in the City column)

however what I think is happening is it's basically trying to assign searchTerm to SearchParameter rather than replacing them with the values?

I've tried various different where statements from what I've found on google but cannot seem to get it to work.

I hope it makes sense what I am meaningş.

Comment: You can't use a parameter to specify your column name like this.
There are other ways to do it, but be aware that they are usually vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: You can't use a parameter for column or table name unless you use dynamic sql I'm afraid. I'm assuming SQL Server here, you haven't tagged the question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to search more than one column name, then try like this,

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE ");

        switch (SearchParameter)
        {
            case "City":
                 sb.Append(" City = @SearchTerm");
                break;

            case "Stadium":
                 sb.Append(" Stadium = @SearchTerm");
                break;
        }

        SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
        selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", SearchTerm);
```

Comment: Remove this code line: `selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchParameter", SearchParameter);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TBL_Locations_Select (
    @City varchar(50), -- or whatever length your actual column is
    @Stadium varchar(50) -- or whatever length your actual column is
)  
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TBL_Locations
WHERE City = CASE WHEN @City IS NULL THEN City ELSE @City END
AND Stadium = CASE WHEN @Stadium IS NULL THEN Stadium ELSE @Stadium END
```

This is sql injection safe and not to bad on performance.
If your City or Stadium is nullable columns you might want to do this a little different:

```
WHERE COALESCE(City, '') = CASE WHEN @City IS NULL THEN COALESCE(City, '') ELSE @City END
AND COALESCE(Stadium, '') = CASE WHEN @Stadium IS NULL THEN COALESCE(Stadium, '') ELSE @Stadium END
```

Then on your c# code you write something like this:

```
string City;
string Stadium;

SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand("TBL_Locations_Select", conn);
selCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", (String.IsNullOrEmpty(City)) ? DBNull.Value : City ;);
selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadium", (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Stadium)) ? DBNull.Value : Stadium ;);
```

Comment: downvoter, care to explain? this approach is working, sql injection safe, and is commonly used. infact, it's so commonly used that it's got it's own name. run a google search on catch-all queries.

Comment: No idea why some people downvote rather than adding a comment.

Comment: @garryp: I have no problem with downvotes, as long as they come with a good reason in the comnents. Infact it may help users to improve answers or delete inapropriate answers. But to downvote without leaving a comment specifing the reason is not very useful unless the reason is already specified in an existing comment.

Answer (score -1):

Change to:

```
String selStmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE City = @SearchTerm";
```

Where "City" is the column in the DB

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to put the column name in there as it has 2 options for what column to search (city or Stadium name)

Comment: The only way would be to dynamically create the string String selStmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE " + colName + " = @SearchTerm"; This is not advisable due to the risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why not use "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE City = @SearchTerm or StadiumName = @SearchTerm"

Comment: This is OK if he knows the fields he'll be filtering on in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
        String selStmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Locations WHERE @SearchParameter = @TextBox1.Text" AND  @SearchTerm = @TextBox2.Text";
        SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selStmt, conn);
        selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchParameter", SearchParameter);
        selCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", SearchTerm);
```

Comment: This will not even compile. Even if you fix the string, it will generate an sql exception.